How to Write Nested Datum in Lucid
I have this in Aiken:
pub type Player {
  X,
  O,
}

pub type Board = List<List<Option<Player>>>

let datum = Datum { 
  board: [[Some(X), Some(O), Some(O)], [Some(X), Some(O), None], [Some(X), Some(X), Some(O)]],
  last_player: O,
}

How do I build datum in Lucid with Data.to? Data.to(new Constr(0, [utf8ToHex("Hello, World!")]))
I can't find documentation that explains or gives examples on this
should it be somethign like?:
Data.to(new Constr(0, 
  [new Constr(0, [new Constr(1, [new Constr(1, [])]), new Constr(1, [new Constr(0, [])]), ... ]), ... ]
)

